# How do I create a table dynamically upon getting a successful ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm returning data from our database and creating a table dynamically. If the call to page1.php is successful, we create a table with one header row and then loop through the results and make some rows. How do I add a single header row? thx!

```
$.post("page1.php", {user: "homer"}, 
function(data){
// output the header row
  function(test){
  var tblHdr ='<th>'+'Username'+'</th>';
  $(tblHdr).appendTo("#tble");
  };

// output the user data
   $.each(data.userdata, 
     function(i,details){

     var tblRow ='<tr>'+'<td>'details.name+'</td>'+'</tr>';
         $(tblRow).appendTo("#tble");

    });
   }, "json"
);
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: I guess not. I didn't think I had to...it seems to do the function(i,details) function without calling it, no? (Keep in mind, I'm VERY new to jQuery/Javascript

Comment: why do you even need or want that function in there? If you remove the whole function declaration from that block and just append the th as defined then you should be fine. assuming tblHdr and tblRow are defined somewhere.

Comment: kai...you are right. I have NO idea what I was thinking. thx! (add it as an answer and I'll accept...otherwise I'll delete my stupid-a** question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you even need or want that function in there? If you remove the whole function declaration from that block and just append the th as defined then you should be fine. assuming tblHdr and tblRow are defined somewhere.

```
$.post("page1.php", {user: "homer"}, 
function(data){
// output the header row

  var tblHdr ='<th>'+'Username'+'</th>';
  $(tblHdr).appendTo("#tble");


// output the user data
   $.each(data.userdata, 
     function(i,details){

     var tblRow ='<tr>'+'<td>'details.name+'</td>'+'</tr>';
         $(tblRow).appendTo("#tble");

    });
   }, "json"
);
```